# Assign var to String inside the same function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function foo() {
     var test =///value;
    <!--and i jave java code inside this script!--> 
    <% String str= // i want to assign it to test value%>

  }
</script>
```

How can i assign `test` to `str` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i assign test to str ??

No simply you cannot.

Java plays on server side and javascript on server side. A client doesn't execute the java code.

You can assign a java value to javascript variable with jsp or Expression language on server side.

To send a javascript value to java you have to make a server request, So the server process your string and send the results back to client.

Most probably you are looking for AJAX request.

- [`Ajax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Do not confuse that JSP and java script existed on same document(or file). Yes but JSP part compiles on server side  and JavaScript executes by browser.

A clear cut example [found here](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/08/ajax-with-jsp-and-servlet-using-jquery.html) for a start.

Comment: so how i can sent selected value from checkbox to string value??